# Java Script Auto Next Page after video ends

Tags: javascript, video

How Do I make the event Click a button  instead of inputting a URL...   because the URL is never the same but the words Next Episode will always be there..

```
// Do not name the function "play()"
function playVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    });
}
</script>
<video controls id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="playVideo()">
    <source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Does your button have an id or some other way of identifying it?

Comment: <a href="LINK" title="episode name"><span>next episode</span> <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

Give your link an id:

```html
<a id="some-id" href="LINK" title="episode name"><span>next episode</span> <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Then change your event listener to this:

```js
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
  document.getElementById('some-id').click();
});
```

Comment: unable to EDIT    its auto generated  and would get broken when the Theme updates

Comment: You mean you're unable to edit the link specifically? If you know the href, you can select it by doing `document.querySelector(a[href="..."])` Either way you'll need *some* way of identifying the link.

Comment: the link is randomly Generated    Per episode.  so there is no other way.   well  there goes the auto next episode idea..

Comment: You can probably still select the link by virtue of the fact that it’s probably the only link on the page that contains an i tag of icon-chevron-right. $(‘a’).has(‘i.icon-chevron-right’).click() or something like it might work.

Comment: That is, if you have jquery. If not, use the equivalent plain JS code.